# Escaping &amp; and CDATA with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Given the following XML:

```
<element><![CDATA[<p>Look at this beautiful house: &amp;#8962;</p>]]></element>
```

This XSL-T:

```
<xsl:template match='/element'>
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

Converts it into:

```
<p>Look at this beautiful house: &amp;#8962;</p>
```

So the CDATA is stripped okay, but how do I convert the `&amp;#8962;` into its proper representation: ⌂ ?

Comment: Well with the CDATA section being present as an escape mechanism the markup inside should be `<p>Look at this beautiful house: &#8962;</p>`. Currently the data uses two escape mechanisms and disable-output-escaping is not going to resolve both of them.

Comment: I understand this problem, but do not know of a good way to solve it through XSL-T.

Comment: You would need to process the text and convert the sequence `&amp;#8962;` to the corresponding character. Easy with XSLT 2.0 and analyze-string or replace, more effort with XSLT 1.0. That's all you can do if the input format can't be changed.

Comment: xslt 2 or 1? in the former you could just use `replace(.,'amp;','')` instead of `.` (but really you should fix whatever software or user is generating the broken input.)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing it with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(current(), '&amp;amp;', '&amp;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

I had to escape the ampersand here because I'm using it directly in XML, so the processor translates it back to `replace(current(), '&amp;', '&')` which is what I wanted.

I'm using XSLT v2 for this since it has the replace function.

Unfortunately, fixing the broken input at the source wasn't possible, a common problem in our field of work. :)

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who happens to stumble into this like I did, here is how I solved this dilemma in my ASP.Net MVC website for a XSLT 1.0 stylesheet. Worked fine for what I was needing. Hopefully it helps you.

First, I wrote this function and included it in my stylesheet:

```
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="functions">
    <msxsl:assembly name="System.Web"/>
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Web"/>
    <![CDATA[       
          public string RemoveAmpersandEncoding(string sText)
          {
            return sText.Replace("&amp;", "&");
          }
    ]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

Then I just called that function later in my stylesheet to get the necessary result:

```
<xsl:value-of select="functions:RemoveAmpersandEncoding(/ReservationsViewData/Campground/CancellationPolicy)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```